# Probability of a 3 digits occurence from a sequence of 64 random hexadecimal symbols?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a software test failing from time to time, due to the fact that the string `123` appears when generating a string with [`SecureRandom.hex(32)` (Ruby)](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), which gives a 64 symbols string.
This includes (A-F) and (0-9), so 16 symbols possible.

I have played a little, and I noticed that it can roughly happens 1500 times over 100,000 calls to the function, so around 1.5%.

What would be the formula to have the exact probability of this test failing?

As a developer, I had to share a little bit of code: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k98qy4xd/14/).

Edit: [Answer's WolframAlpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+(%E2%88%921)%5E(m+%2B+1)+*+((64%E2%88%922m)+choose+m)*+16%5E(64%E2%88%923m)+,+m%3D1+to+21)+%2F+16%5E64)

```
54392126209570846953192790832763093471349103670511891931049735583247364107/
3618502788666131106986593281521497120414687020801267626233049500247285301248
≈0.0150317
≈1.50317%
```

Comment: Should'nt it be (A-F)  and 16 symbols?

Comment: You are absolutely right, and hex(32) actually returns 64 symbols too :)

Comment: Not an answer, but if you are interested in an estimate, assuming each of the 62 3-digit sequences to be independent gives $1 - (1 - (1/16)^3)^{62} \approx 1.502\%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exact answer, via Inclusion Exclusion Principle:

Let $A_i =$ the set of 64-long strings where "123" appears starting at the $i$th position ($1 \le i \le 62$).  E.g. if "123" appears at both the 2nd and 40th positions in string $x$, then $x \in A_2$ and $x \in A_{40}$, i.e. $x \in A_2 \cap A_{40} $.

Then $S = \bigcup_i A_i=$ the set of strings where "123" appears at least once, and your desired probability is $|S|/16^{64}$.

The Inclusion Exclusion Principle gives:

$$|S| = |\bigcup A_i| = \sum_i |A_i| - \sum_{i<j} |A_i \cap A_j| + \sum_{i<j<k} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - \dots    $$

Obviously $|A_i| = 16^{61}$ as the other 61 positions can be anything.  So the first term is $\sum_i |A_i| = 62 \cdot 16^{61}$.

Now two occurrences of "123" cannot overlap (unlike e.g. if you're looking for "111" in which case they CAN overlap).  So if $j - i < 3$, then $|A_i \cap A_j| = 0$.  For the non-trivial case of $j - i \ge 3$, the other $64 - 3 - 3 = 58$ positions can be filled with anything, so $|A_i \cap A_j| = 16^{58}$.

Meanwhile, how many $(i, j)$ pairs are there s.t. $j - i \ge 3$?  Imagine "merging" each "123" into a new character "!", so the final string length is now $64-2-2 = 60$ instead and there are two "!" characters.  The number of ways to do this is simply ${60 \choose 2}$.  Thus the 2nd term is:

$$ \sum_{i<j} |A_i \cap A_j| = {60 \choose 2} 16^{58}$$

The $m$th term is similar and we have:

$$ \sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_m} |A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_m}| = {64 - 2m \choose m} 16^{64 - 3m} $$

So the final result is:

$$ |S| = \sum_{m=1}^{21} (-1)^{m+1} {64 - 2m \choose m} 16^{64 - 3m} $$

Comment: Awesome, I would have never been able to compute that!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

> We consider the set words of length $n\geq 0$ built from the alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{0,\ldots,9,A,\ldots,F\}$ and the set $B=\{123\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> - We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of these words of length $n$.
> - Since we are looking for the number of words which contain the bad word $123$, the resulting generating function is the generating function of *all* words minus $f(s)$
>     \begin{align*}
>   &1+16s+16^2s^2+16^3s^3\cdots-f(s)=\frac{1}{1-16s}-f(s)
>   \end{align*}

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=16$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[123])
\end{align*}

We calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[123])&=-s^3\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

> It    follows  from  (1)  and (2)
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(s)=\frac{1}{1-16s+s^3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the generated function counting all strings which contain $123$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-16s}-\frac{1}{1-16s+s^3}}=s^3 + \color{blue}{32} s^4 + 768 s^5 + 16\,383 s^6 +\cdots\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficients of the series were calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha. We see for  instance there are $\color{blue}{32}$ words of length $4$ which  contain the *bad* word $123$. These are $$(0..9,A..F)123\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 123(0..9,A..F).$$

**The coefficient of $s^{n}$**

In fact we are interested in the coefficient of $s^{64}$. We calculate the coefficient of $s^n$ from (3). It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[s^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $s^n$ of a series.

We obtain from (3) for $n\geq 0$

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[s^n]}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{1-16s}-\frac{1}{1-16s+s^3}\right)}\\
&=[s^n]\sum_{m=0}^\infty 16^ms^m-[s^n]\sum_{m=0}^\infty s^m(16-s^2)^m\\
&=16^n-[s^n]\sum_{m=0}^\infty s^m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^ks^{2k}16^{m-k}\\
&=16^n-\sum_{m=0}^n[s^{n-m}]\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^ks^{2k}16^{m-k}\\
&=16^n-\sum_{m=0}^n[s^m]\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}(-1)^ks^{2k}16^{n-m-k}\\
&=16^n-\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} [s^{2m}]\sum_{k=0}^{n-2m}\binom{n-2m}{k}(-1)^ks^{2k}16^{n-2m-k}\\
&=16^n-\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}\binom{n-2m}{m}(-1)^m16^{n-3m}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}\binom{n-2m}{m}(-1)^{m+1}16^{n-3m}}\tag{4}\\
\end{align*}

> Finally we obtain from (4) in accordance with the answer of @antkam the wanted probability
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[s^{64}]}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{1-16s}-\frac{1}{1-16s+s^3}\right)16^{-64}}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=1}^{21}\binom{64-2m}{m}(-1)^{m+1}16^{-3m}}\\
> &\color{blue}{\simeq 0.01503\,16662\,40506}
> \end{align*}
>
> which gives roughly $\color{blue}{1.5\%}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick hint: total number of all possible strings is $16^{32}$, the number of strings that contain at least one occurrence of "$123$" is $32 \cdot 16^{29}=2\cdot 16^{30}$  ($32$ spots to put substring "$123$" and we need to fill remaining $29$ positions). The probability for truly random generation should be $$\frac{2\cdot 16^{30}}{16^{32}}=\frac{1}{128}$$

Comment: the string length is 64, there are 62 places to put "123", and this argument double-counts the cases where "123" appears twice, etc.